# Hide route in React Navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Is there a way to hide a route in the drawer but still be able to navigate to it?

Example: I want get rid of *Post* in the drawer but I want be able to navigate to a `<Post>` component.

[image]

Comment: May this not possible in build in drawer. You have to create your custom drawer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Put the `Post` screen inside a stack with another screen and use that stack nested in drawer.
2. Use a custom component for drawer to manually specify which items to show: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/drawer-navigator.html#drawercontent